# how to find related category in index part?

Tags: mysql, php

I developed a header which have different head and  those head have  drop down like this as shown in pic [image: Front end of page]

and now all head have separate database table for connecting more drop down and all table have same attribute name i.e. id and category [image]

now i wanted that when i select any drop down value and that value is equal to post table attribute tags that database row should show on index page here is my code

```
<?if(isset($_GET['cat']))
 {
     $cat_name=$_GET['cat'];
     $c_query="select * from private ,goverment,others,location,qaulification,company where category=$cat_name";
     $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","joboard");
     $c_run=mysqli_query($con,$c_query);
     $c_row=mysqli_fetch_array($c_run);
     $c_name=$c_row['category'];
 }
 ?>
```

## All Job Board  Order By Date

```
            if(isset($_POST['submitSearch']))
            {
                $search=$_POST['search'];
                $query  = "select * from posts where status='publish'";
                $query.=" and tags like '%$search%'";
                $query.="order by id desc";
            }
            else
            {
                $query  = "select * from posts where status='publish'";
                if(isset($c_name))
                {
                $query.=" and tags='$c_name'";
                }
               $query.="order by id desc";  

            }

           $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","joboard");
           $run=mysqli_query($con, $query);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($run)>0)
            {
             while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run))
                {
                   $id=$row['id'];
                   $title=$row['title'];
                   $content=$row['content'];
                   $image=$row['image'];
                   $title=$row['title'];
                   $date=$row['date'];
                   $url=$row['url'];

           ?>

            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" >
            <div class="panel" style="border: 1px solid blue">
       <div class="panel-heading">
           <div class="row" style="border-radius:200px;">
               <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-left" style="margin-left: -13px;
                                                                        margin-top: -10px;" >
                   <a href="post.php?post_id=<?php echo $id;?>"><img src="<?php echo $image;?>" width="100" height="100"></a>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-9" style="text-align:center;">
                   <a href="post.php?post_id=<?php echo $id;?>">
                       <h3 style="margin-top: 0px;
                                  margin-right: -33px;"><?php echo $title;?> </h3></a>
                   <p style="text-align:justify; margin-right: -20px; padding-left: 25px;"> <?php echo $content;?> </p>
                    <a href="post.php?post_id=<?php echo $id;?>" class="btn btn-primary"> Details</a>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
                        <div class="panel-footer " style="color:black;
                                                          font-size:15px;">
                            <div class="row" style="padding-top:5px;
                                                    margin-bottom:-5px;
                                                    margin-top:-5px;">
                                <div class="col-xs-6  col-sm-6 col-md-6" > Last Date Apply<span class="pull-right"><i class=" fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> </span></div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6  col-sm-6 col-md-6"> <?php echo $date;?></div>
                            </div>
                            <hr style="width:100%;
                                       border:1px solid ccc#;">
                            <div class="row" style="padding-top:5px;
                                                    margin-top:-15px;">
                                <div class="col-xs-5  col-sm-5 col-md-5">Apply here<span class="pull-right"><i class=" fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> </span></div>
                                <div class="col-xs-7  col-sm-7 col-md-7" style="text-align:justify;"> <a href="#"><?php echo $url;?></a></div>
                            </div>
                               <div class="clearfix"></div>
                           </div>

                   </div>
               </div>
           <?php
               }
           }
           else
           {
               echo"<h3>No Related Post Here Search Something Else Thank you </h3>";
           }
            ?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: Also, **never** get your web app to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes,
so on top of the SQL injection vulnerabilities
this just leaves your database an open book for hackers.
Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly.

Comment: Beyond those general observations, your question is unclear. What problem are you facing? You told us what you want, but not what is going wrong when you try it. At a guess, if you want the values of multiple different dropdowns to be taken into account in your query, you need to build up your query with a series of AND clauses, which you only actually incorporate into the query if the dropdown had an option chosen. But not sure if that's what you really mean or not.

Comment: Your current SELECT makes no sense and will do a massive cross join onto all your tables. You need to use inner joins (or left joins if the fields are optional in the DB) between the tables. I think you maybe need to study basic SQL syntax a little more before attempting this.